# Java: how to make bufferedreader loop through input file, and run code blocks once

Tags: java, bufferedreader

...sorry for the length...  ...and the goofy code/text entries. I'm still a noob.

I need to parse through Trimble differential correction log files (example follows) get specified values, and put them into a .csv file for QA before uploading to Oracle. I chose Java for professional development because it's the language used to develop other in-house software.

I'm pointing to a single file until I can get the output correct, then I'll work on looping through file structures.

My requirement: Read log (.txt UTF-16LE) and get specific values from several mostly similar blocks of text; then find additional values in subsequent mostly similar (but different from the first blocks) blocks of text. Put those values into a .csv for import into a spreadsheet for QA per log file.

The values in the text blocks can vary, but all potential variations are known.

I'm only concerned about the first blocks of text, ATM. The REGEX for all the values I'm interested in are below.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class LogParser
{
    public static void main (String[] args)throws IOException
    {
        //log file Reader init:
        File corrFile = new File("D:\\Utilities\\Development\\Java\\HPGPSLogParser\\Correct_2015-10-13_10-51.txt");
        BufferedReader corrReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(corrFile),"UTF-16LE"));
        String corrText = "";
        String corrLine = "";
/*
NOTE: PFO diffcorr log files are encoded in UTF-16 LE
*/

        //Writer init:
        File stateCSV = new File("D:\\Utilities\\Development\\Java\\HPGPSLogParser\\MH.csv");
        BufferedWriter corrWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(stateCSV, true));
        String fileText = "";

        //output reader variables:
        String corrOutput = "";
        String outputLine = "";

        //Management variables: ID location & specify actions:
        String roverFile = "Rover file: ";
        String procRoverFile = "Processing rover file, ";
        String carrProcess = "";
        String codeProces = "";

        //regex variables:
        Pattern fileName1 = Pattern.compile("Rover file: (?<fileName1>[A-Z]{2}-\\d{3}-\\d{5}-SP\\d\\.SSF)+");
        Pattern noBase = Pattern.compile("(?<noBase>No matching base data found)");
        Pattern totalCoverage = Pattern.compile("(?<totalCoverage>[\\d]{1,3})\\% total coverage");
        Pattern coverageBy = Pattern.compile("(?<coverageBy>[\\d]{1,3})+\\% coverage by (?<baseStation>\\b\\w+\\b\\.[zZ].*)+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
        Pattern carrierProcessing = Pattern.compile("Carrier processing\\.\\.\\.");
        Pattern fileName2 = Pattern.compile("Processing rover file, (?<fileName2>[A-Z]{2}-\\d{3}-\\d{5}-SP\\d\\.SSF)+ \\.\\.\\.");
        Pattern noProc = Pattern.compile("(?<noProc>No processing performed as base data does not have carrier data)");
        Pattern noCarDat = Pattern.compile("(?<noCarDat>No carrier processing performed as file has no carrier data)");
        Pattern selectedPositions = Pattern.compile("Selected (?<selectedPositions>\\d{1,6}) positions for post-processing");
        Pattern correctedPositions = Pattern.compile("Corrected (?<correctedPositions>\\d{1,6}) positions");
        Pattern correctFailed = Pattern.compile("Failed to correct (?<correctFailed>\\d{1,6}) positions");
        Pattern carrierMissingBase = Pattern.compile("(?<carrierMissingBase>\\d{1,6}) of these were due to missing base data");
        Pattern carrierInsuffSat = Pattern.compile("(?<carrierInsuffSat>\\d{1,6}) of these were due to insufficient satellites for position fix");
        Pattern codeProcessing = Pattern.compile("Code processing\\.\\.\\.");
        Pattern refGap = Pattern.compile("(?<refGap>Reference station data gap encountered: )");
        Pattern codeChose = Pattern.compile("Chose (?<codeChose>\\d{1,6}) code solutions over the carrier solutions");
        Pattern codeHighQual = Pattern.compile("(?<codeHighQual>\\d{1,6}) code solutions were of higher quality");
        Pattern filtered = Pattern.compile("Filtered out (?<filtered>\\d{1,6}) uncorrected positions");

            try(corrReader)
            {
                while ((corrLine = corrReader.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    corrText = corrLine.trim();
                    Matcher carrProcMatcher = carrierProcessing.matcher(corrText);
                    if (corrText.contains(roverFile))
                    {
                        Matcher file1Matcher = fileName1.matcher(corrText); //first order variable based on 'Rover file: fileName1'
                        if(file1Matcher.find())
                        {
                            String firstFileName = file1Matcher.group("fileName1");
                            if (corrOutput.equals(""))
                            {
                                corrOutput += firstFileName+",";
                            } else {
                                corrOutput += "\n"+firstFileName+",";
                            } //end else
                        Matcher baseMatcher = noBase.matcher(corrText);
                        if(baseMatcher.find()) 
                        {
                            String noBaseText = baseMatcher.group("noBase");
                            if(noBaseText.equals("No matching base data found"))
                            {
                                corrOutput += "TRUE"+",";
                            } else {
                                corrOutput += ",";
                            } //end else
                        } 
                        Matcher totCovMatcher = totalCoverage.matcher(corrText);
                        if(totCovMatcher.find()) 
                        {
                            String totalCovText = totCovMatcher.group("totalCoverage");
                            corrOutput += totalCovText+",";
                        }
                        Matcher covByMatcher = coverageBy.matcher(corrText);
                        if(covByMatcher.find()) 
                        {
                            String covByPct = covByMatcher.group("coverageBy");
                            String covByProvider = covByMatcher.group("baseStation");
                            corrOutput += covByPct+","+covByProvider+",";
                        }
                corrWriter.write(corrOutput);
                corrWriter.flush();
                        } // end file1Matcher if
                    } //end corrText.contains if
                } //end while loop
//              corrWriter.write(corrOutput);
                corrWriter.close();
                corrReader.close();
            } //end try corrReader

    } //end main method

} //end class
```

The log content of the log files that I'm interested in look like:

> --------Coverage Details:--------------------
>
> Rover file: AA-123-12345-SP1.SSF
>
> Local time: 2/11/2014 8:06:30 PM to 2/11/2014 8:37:15 PM
>
> 100% total coverage
>
> 100% coverage by guug04314054.zip
>
> Rover file: AA-321-54321-SP1.SSF
>
> Local time: 2/3/2015 4:06:14 PM to 2/3/2015 4:06:44 PM
>
> 0% total coverage.  No matching base data found.
>
> Rover file: AA-132-12354-SP2.SSF
>
> Local time: 2/17/2014 5:51:01 PM to 2/17/2014 6:18:57 PM
>
> 100% total coverage
>
> 4% coverage by guug04914003.zip
>
> 100% coverage by guug04914022.zip

I need my output to look like:

AA-123-12345-SP1.SSF,,100,100,guug04914003.zip,

or

AA-312-12435-SP1.SSF,TRUE,0,,,

My code is looping through the input file multiple times, generating repeat entries. How do I get a single output entry per 'Rover file:' text block?

Thanks!!

Comment: Does `try(corrReader)` actually compile?

Comment: @SeanBright Try-with-variable is a feature added in Java 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only loop through file once. Read and collect data as you go. Don't build output until you have all the data. When you see a new `Rover file` entry, write output (unless first entry) and clear values. When you reach the end, write output (if any).

Isolating code in a class might make it easier to reuse printing logic.

Example:

```
public final class LogEntry {
    private final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Rover file: (.*)" +
                                                   "|(\\d+)% total coverage" +
                                                   "|(\\d+)% coverage by (.*)");
    private String roverFile;
    private Integer totalCoverage;
    private Map<String, Integer> fileCoverage = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    public void process(BufferedReader in) throws IOException {
        for (String line; (line = in.readLine()) != null; ) {
            Matcher m = this.pattern.matcher(line);
            if (! m.matches())
                continue;
            if (m.start(1) != -1) {
                print();
                clear();
                this.roverFile = m.group(1);
            } else if (m.start(2) != -1) {
                this.totalCoverage = Integer.valueOf(m.group(2));
            } else if (m.start(3) != -1) {
                this.fileCoverage.put(m.group(4), Integer.valueOf(m.group(3)));
            }
        }
        print();
    }

    private void clear() {
        this.roverFile = null;
        this.totalCoverage = null;
        this.fileCoverage.clear();
    }

    private void print() {
        if (this.roverFile == null)
            return;
        if (this.fileCoverage.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(this.roverFile + "," + this.totalCoverage);
        } else {
            for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : this.fileCoverage.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(this.roverFile + "," + this.totalCoverage + "," + entry.getValue() + "," + entry.getKey());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Test*

```
String input = "Rover file: AA-123-12345-SP1.SSF\n" +
               "Local time: 2/11/2014 8:06:30 PM to 2/11/2014 8:37:15 PM\n" +
               "100% total coverage\n" +
               "100% coverage by guug04314054.zip\n" +
               "Rover file: AA-321-54321-SP1.SSF\n" +
               "Local time: 2/3/2015 4:06:14 PM to 2/3/2015 4:06:44 PM\n" +
               "0% total coverage. No matching base data found.\n" +
               "Rover file: AA-132-12354-SP2.SSF\n" +
               "Local time: 2/17/2014 5:51:01 PM to 2/17/2014 6:18:57 PM\n" +
               "100% total coverage\n" +
               "4% coverage by guug04914003.zip\n" +
               "100% coverage by guug04914022.zip\n";
try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(input))) {
    new LogEntry().process(in);
}
```

*Output*

```
AA-123-12345-SP1.SSF,100,100,guug04314054.zip
AA-321-54321-SP1.SSF,0
AA-132-12354-SP2.SSF,100,4,guug04914003.zip
AA-132-12354-SP2.SSF,100,100,guug04914022.zip
```

Comment: Thanks @Andreas! Just for reference, I ended up with the same result (= some additional logic) by executing the writer outside of the while loop.  :)